# Leaves (emission) from point

Tags: particles

I am still figuring out the basics here...
I can't figure out how to have my leaves come out from a vertex of my branch.  My leaf image is always centered to the branch, instead of the end of the leaf naturally coming out from the branch.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

**Blend file:**

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ It's really hard to tell after this screenshot.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2268" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2268/)

Comment: @LukeD  Here you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your leaf on second layer and go to *Edit mode*.
2. Select bottom face and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*.

[image: 1]

3. Go back to *Object mode* and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D cursor*.

[image: 2]

That's all.

If you want, you can select only two bottom vertices and do the rest same as above.

Or you can even manually position 3D cursor, it's up to you.