# Branch starting not from bark using hair particle system

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I am new at blender and I ran into a problem creating a tree using particle system hairs. I tried following a tutorial which shows how to make branches separetly (I creatied them from images in another layer, made them into a group) and use them when making a tree's branches. I have done it. Problem is that my branches don't start from the bark, their middle is on the bark, their start is on the other side of the bark. I don't know how to explain, so this is how it looks like:
[image]

And this is how I would like it to be (I photoshoped it):
[image]

So can you please tell me what to do to achieve what I want or maybe how to make a tree in another way? The reason why I have chose this kind of making of a tree is because I will you it in a game and I need it to have as few faces as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaves (emission) from point](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67460/leaves-emission-from-point) This answer is for leaves, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to name the problem so I could find the solution, but this helped!